# Necessity of using rdfs:Datatype in RDF code

Tags: rdf, rdfs

In a text book ([A Developer’s Guide to the Semantic Web
by *Yu, Liyang*](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783662437957)), in page 143, it suggests that, "it is always useful to
clearly declare that a given URI represents a datatype, as shown here:". Then it shows the following code:

```
<rdf:Property
    rdf:about1⁄4"http://www.liyangyu.com/camera#model">
<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Camera"/>
<rdfs:range
    rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdfs:Datatype
    rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
```

I fail to understand the necessity of the last two lines. As far as my knowledge goes, `XMLSchema#string` will be good for any string. And as is delineated [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_datatype), `rdfs:Datatype` is "the class of datatypes".

What do we lose if we do not use the last two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All primitive types [differ](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-xsch-datatypes/#sec-values-differ), though reasoners may or might [think](http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/Protege-4-3-0-5-HermiT-strange-reasoning-behaviour-tp4661177p4661180.html) in the opposite way.

The supertype (⊆) of  all the primitive types is `rdfs:Literal`, which is not to be confused with `rdf:PlainLiteral`, and which is analogous to `xsd:anySimpleType`.

The type (∈) of all the primitive types is `rdfs:Datatype`.

In the previous edition (2011), Liyang Yu wrote right after the piece you quote:

> The next example will show that using rdfs:Datatype is not only a good
>   practice, but also necessary in some cases.

I believe, this example wasn't excluded in 2014 edition.

Comment: Yes, I saw that example. But I did not find it convincing enough for the previous code (the code we are considering).

Answer (score 1):

The last 2 lines seem to be quite useless. These lines say that `xsd:string` is a datatype. Either the RDF engine already knows that `xsd:string` is a datatype and can process literals with this type (which is the case of most RDF engines and is anyway required by RDF 1.1), or it does not, in which case knowing that it is a datatype does not really help because it is not sufficient to determine what lexical forms are valid and what the value space is.

Either way, the two lines do not provide information that is useful for further processing or entailment that is of interest to any application, as far as I can imagine.